# Batch move files to a subfolder based on list of filenames

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am not a coder and have absolutely zero coding/computing knowledge. I have tried my best to follow the solutions given by others in response to similar questions to mine but am getting nowhere fast.

Basically I am looking for a solution that will let me batch move some wav files from one folder, into a subfolder (that I have already set up in the same place), based on a list of filenames that I have in a text file.

I have a script, but it isn't working. It could be the script, or even something else really stupid I'm overlooking in the process I'm going through as this is the first time I have ever tried to do something like this. I will explain exactly what I've done and if anyone can enlighten me as to where I am going wrong that would be amazing...

I have set the execution policy in Powershell so it will allow me to run scripts.

I have made a file called filemovescript.ps1 which contains the following script:

```
@echo off
set "Source=E:\Dissertation\My deployment data\Data to analyse\combined set"
set "Target=E:\Dissertation\My deployment data\Data to analyse\combined set\Barbastelle"
set "FileList=E:\Dissertation\My deployment data\Data to analyse\combined set\Barbastelle_list.txt"
echo.

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do (
   for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir "%Source%\%%a" /b /s /a-d ') do echo copying "%%b"&xcopy /b "%%b" "%Target%%%~pb" >nul
)
:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

All my wav files (about 10k of them) are in the folder 'combined set'. The text file Barbastelle_list.txt contains a list of the filenames of a subset of those wav files, like this:

TL_20170531_034316.wav

TL_20170514_012440.wav

TL_20170531_034717.wav

TL_20170524_215307.wav

I want the script to move the files specified in the text file into the subfolder 'Barbastelle'.

I have opened a Powershell window (powershell.exe - there are also options to open powershell_ise - I don't know what the difference is) from the start menu and pasted in this script text above. Powershell then gives me back the following:

```
At line:1 char:7
+ @echo off
+       ~~~
Unexpected token 'off' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:3
+ if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & got ...
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:7 char:65
+ ... ot exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Ex ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:8 char:3
+ if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & got ...
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:8 char:65
+ ... ot exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Ex ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:9 char:3
+ if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:11 char:4
+ for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do (
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At line:12 char:84
+ ...  in ('dir "%Source%\%%a" /b /s /a-d ') do echo copying "%%b"&xcopy /b ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:1 char:1
+ @echo off
+ ~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@echo' can be used only as an
argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$echo'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I took this script from another question on this site, and it seemed to work for them so am really unsure where I'm going wrong - and I understand none of the above feedback from Powershell! How can I make this work?

Comment: Your script is not Powershell code at all, but a `cmd` batch script. So no wonder Powershell gets a belly-ache from it.

Comment: Hi Hans, well that explains it then! Like I said I know nothing about this...so my next question would be, what could I write in powershell to do the same thing, or, how do I run a cmd batch script? Thank you.

Comment: I rarely use Windows, but I believe that you should begin by renaming `filemovescript.ps1` to `filemovescript.cmd` - and then either click on the file or do a `Invoke-Item filemovescript.cmd` in a Powershell window.

Comment: thanks - I have now successfully used the powershell script provided by SteloNLD, but nonetheless appreciate your time to respond!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments of your question, you cant put batch into a Powershell console.

A quick PowerShell sample i made:

```
#initialisation
CLS
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$VerbosePreference = "continue"

#Settings
$SubFolder = ".\Barbastelle"
$FileListFile = ".\Barbastelle_list.txt"

#Retrieve List with Files to move from current folder.
Try { [Array]$FilesToMove = Get-Content $FileListFile }
Catch {Write-Warning "could not load $($FileListFile)"; Start-Sleep -S 3 ; Exit}

#If subfolder does not exist then create it.
If (!(Test-Path $SubFolder)) {
    Try { New-Item $SubFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null}
    Catch {Write-Warning "Could not create subfolder $($SubFolder)"; Start-Sleep -S 3 ; Exit}
}

#Try to moving the files from the list to the the specified subfolder.
Foreach ($File in $FilesToMove) {

    #If File does not exist then skip.
    If (!(Test-Path $File)) {
        Write-Verbose "File $($File) Does not exist, skipping"
        Continue
    }

    # Check if files already exist in the sub folder.
    If (Test-Path (Join-Path -Path $SubFolder -ChildPath $File)){
        Write-Verbose "File $($File) exists already in the subfolder, skipping"
        Continue    
    }


    #try copying the file.
    Try {
        $File | Move-Item -Destination $SubFolder;
        Write-Verbose "File $($File) succesfully moved."
    }
    Catch {Write-Warning "Could not move file $($File), Skipping"; Continue}        
}

Write-Verbose "Script finished, waiting for 5 seconds before closing."
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

This only works if the console is working from the specified directory,
Navigate to it with 'cd "Path/to/directory"' or run the script directly from the folder with the 'Run with Powershell' option.

Comment: Wow, I just tried it and it works perfectly! Thank you so much for this, I really really appreciate it. Happy days :)